# Create build flavor on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I'm new on Flutter but I'm Android developer.

When I created a new Android project. I always prepare two build variant `debug` and `release` which provide me a `BuildConfig.DEBUG` variable with the value depended on which build variant I choose. I'm not sure about iOS. However, when I created a new Flutter project, I cant find the ways to point the gradle build me something like that.

Example code:

```
class RikimaruApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Rikimaru Application",
      theme: ThemeData(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,  \\ => debugShowCheckedModeBanner: BuildConfig.DEBUG,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Android Studio]

I searched Google with `flutter build variants` key word but fail. Please teach me how to research about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword word would be **flutter flavour**

And you can check this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) for more information on flutter flavouring.

Comment: Thank U for your sharing.

Comment: Both Google and Apple provide flavours for different "types" of the app like a free and paid version. All flavours of an app should be stage tested. So using a flavor for staging is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

there is no magic bullet for that. and it's easy i think.
you can use this link that is suggested by google :
https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36

and it can be in few steps :

**-Creating new config files in flutter app ( each can have flavor to run ) .**

[image]

**-having that "Build flavor" name in android and ios** ..   android should be **productFlavors**...ios should be **Schemas** .. choose config for run in flutter and Well Done!

Comment: Thank you for your answering this question. The updated feature "36805 Allow flavors and custom build types in host app" are support at release version 1.9.1 (30 Jul - 5 month after I ask this question).